# Installing MySQL libmysqlclient-dev and UDF files on Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, unix, homebrew, udf

I am trying to install the following package on my mac in order to test my API on my local environment but thus far I have not succeeded.

https://github.com/spachev/mysql_udf_bundle

I have tried various things such as:

```
brew install libmysqlclient-dev
```

This produced the following error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "libmysqlclient-dev" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I am used to working on CentOS so am not particularly familiar with the likes of `apt` and `brew`... Can anyone advise me on how best to install this on my Mac?

Not sure if it is of any relevance but I am running Mac OSX 10.11.4 (El Capitan).

I did **NOT** install MySQL using `brew install mysql`, instead, I followed the instructions here: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2015/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-el-capitan/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try installing mysql-connector-c:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Comment: It should now be `brew install mysql-client` after the package was renamed.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22287595)

Comment: @NicoHaase This is an answer.

Comment: @Zoe there is no explanation given why that should work, and there is an accepted and upvoted answer - so I'd assume that there is some information missing

Comment: @NicoHaase no explanation to a code-only answer [does not warrant flags or review deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality)